# How to fail if a certain program is run?

Tags: bash, path, cmake

I am using [cmake-conan](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan) to call conan during my build (on Ubuntu 16.04). However now I want to test that certain builds do NOT call conan.

cmake-conan calls conan in this fashion:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${conan_command} ${conan_args}
                     RESULT_VARIABLE return_code
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

Where ${conan_command} resolves to `conan`.

What I tried is to alias `conan` to `fail` in my bash script, however it doesn't seem to be picked up by cmake.

```
alias conan='fail'
```

Is there another way to make sure that a program is not found in PATH even though it actually is in PATH?

Comment: Don't call `conan` directly, earlier in the process create a link to it that you switch between `conan` and `fail` as need, and call `conan` through that link.

Answer (score 0):

In `CMake` script run `conan_cmake_run` macro with params `CONAN_COMMAND "fail"`

You can pass CONAN_COMMAND as ENVIRNOMENT variable:

```
…
conan_cmake_run(CONAN_COMMAND $ENV{CONAN_COMMAND)
…
```

and:

```
CONAN_COMMAND=fail cmake …
```

or pass as variable:

```
…
conan_cmake_run(CONAN_COMMAND ${CONAN_COMMAND)
…
```

and:

```
cmake -DCONAN_COMMAND=fail …
```

Comment: I solved my issue by injecting a fake conan script in the PATH before the test, your method works only for testing once, not continually.